# Failed to install set of modules in python

Tags: python, pip, python-3.5

I try to use the following modules:

```
win32gui, win32ui, win32con, win32api
```

First, I tried to install these modules with pip3:

```
pip3 install <Each module above>
```

I got the error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <Each module above> (from version: )
No matching distribution found for <Each module above>
```

Then I tried the following solution as suggested in many questions as mine:

```
pip3 install pypiwin32
```

Then modules have yet to work for me (note that I haven't changed modules name)..

Where am I wrong?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/

Comment: @thebjorn So I need to "pip3 install pywin32" rather than "pip3 install pypiwin32"?

Edit: I did "pip3 install pywin32" , I got: "Requirement already satisfied..."

Comment: If you click on the homepage button, and read a little bit down, it's suggested to install from binaries (https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases) if you don't there are some manual steps to do if you want to register COM objects or program Windows services (refer to the README file for details).

Comment: @thebjorn I don't understand.. (SORRY IN ADVANCE). Once I do "pip3 install pywin32" I should be able to write "import win32api" (for example) without any problems?

Comment: If you don't use the .msi installer there are some manual steps that should be performed (check the docs), but yes, that's it (works for me at least).